# Newspaper Bridges

Tags: us8937118

In reference to the patent: [US8937118](https://www.google.com/patents/US8937118)

Does using newspaper and masking tape for bridge building violate this patent in any way shape or form? If so how do we ascertain the rights to build said bridge.

Comment: Are you planning on using motor oil or used cooking oil?

Answer (score 0):

The coverage of a patent is defined by its claims. In order to infringe on a patent, you need to incorporate each and every element of at least one claim. In this case the first (and only independent) claim reads:

> 1. A solid load-bearing article provided in a three-dimensional geometric shape, said article including at least some content of a
>      first recyclable component including at least one constituent selected
>      from the group consisting of paper, paperboard, and clothing fibers,
>      and any combination thereof; at least some content of a second
>      recyclable component including at least one constituent selected from
>      the group consisting of wood chips and wood strips, and at least one
>      constituent selected from the group consisting of used motor oil, used
>      cooking oil, and a combination thereof; and a third recyclable
>      component including at least some content of polypropylene fibers;
>      wherein said article further includes structural additives selected
>      from the group consisting of perlite, pozzolan, calcium hydroxide,
>      Portland Cement, and any combination thereof.

As you can see, one element of this claim includes either used motor oil or used cooking oil. In addition you need to include a structural additive selected from perlite, pozzolan, calcium hydroxide and Portland Cement. Therefore if you are building your bridge from only newspaper and masking tape you are completely free and clear from infringement of this patent.